# Apache - Redirect user to url via Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, redirect

I have an Apache webserver. Now users can access the apache front end url, which is:

```
http://192.168.32.32
```

Now, when the user visits that url, apache should automatically redirect him to a new url, but via a proxy server on a specific port: 192.169.34.34 3128

The redirect url can only be accessed via the proxy server, and apache can access the proxy server because they are on the same domain.

How do you do this in apache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain on what you want to do, but I think what you are after can be achieved with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) in combination with [mod_rewite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/). I could be that you only need mod_proxy, I guess it depends on how much tuning options you want.

Maybe [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) is what you are after?